# How to control the behavior of tooltip on google chart

Tags: html, css, charts

when i click on google chart point, In tooltip it is showing 'See sample book'. 
I want to control the enable and disable property on tooltip using the code.
As of now enable and disable is working with mouse over event but i want to remove this and simply enable and disable the 'see sample block' using programming.

At first point it should be disable its working fine[image]

second point should be enable but it showing disable when mouse over it showing as enable . I need this should be happen as soon as i click the point in the graph.
[image]

My HTML code is here:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript"
          src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={
            'modules':[{
              'name':'visualization',
              'version':'1',
              'packages':['corechart']
            }]
          }"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
          ['2004',  1000,      400],
          ['2005',  1170,      460],
          ['2006',  660,       1120],
          ['2007',  1030,      540]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Company Performance',
          legend: { position: 'bottom' },
          tooltip: { trigger: 'selection' }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

        chart.setAction({
          id: 'sample',
          text: 'See sample book',
          enabled:function()
          {

            if (typeof(chart.getSelection) == 'undefined')
                return false;
            if (typeof (chart.getSelection()[0]) == 'undefined')
                return false;
            selection = chart.getSelection();
            var ans = selection[0].row;

            if(ans == 0)
            {
              return false;
            }
            else
            {
              return true;
            }
          },
          action: function() {
            selection = chart.getSelection();
            alert(selection[0].row);

            }          
        });

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="curve_chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can set the tooltip to HTML, this should give you more control of how it operates, and what it displays. To do this, add a tooltip column to your chart, when you're building the chart with columns and rows

`data.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'annotation', 'p': { 'html': true } });`

As you can see, we are setting the tooltip information to be html instead of SVG, and the data you want to populate into your tooltip, should be added as a row to your chart, corresponding to the column.

To modify the tooltip behaviour, you can use the options you pass to the chart, and add the isHtml to true

`tooltip: { trigger: selection, isHtml: true }`

To make additional changes to your tooltip, in css, you can add this line to your CSS and start overriding the default css

`div.google-visualization-tooltip {
}`